# Using TensorFlow to do regression on a 13 column data set

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, data-science

I would like to do regression on a 13 column data set. The second column is dependent on the rest of the 12 columns. All column contains real number values.

How can I create a neural network using TensorFlow to do the regression? I have tried going through this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide/) but it is too advanced for me.

Thanks in advance for a MWE.

Comment: The tutorial you have mentioned is very simple. What is the part you don't understand?

Comment: @Rob, I didn't understand how I should create the binary column in my case. Here is the descriptive statistics of the dependent column.        Mean -2.0552677366
Standard Error 0.0311238596
Mode 0
Median -0.17276868
Variance 45.1692622768
Standard Deviation 6.7208081565
Kurtosis 72.8788782322
Skewness 0.9903042325
Range 330.25942
Minimum -140.53192
Maximum 189.7275
Sum -95835.0792920298
Count 46629

Comment: @Rob, moreover, the code does not look to be creating neural network.

Comment: I understand now your question, I have written an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In that tutorial they are using logistic regression, that is a linear binary classifier. They use the class tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier as their model.

If you use class tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor then you can do linear regression instead of classification.

In that webpage you have tutorials for other models. If you want to create a neural network you have different tutorial in the left menu, for example:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

In this repository you have python notebooks with the full code of many different neural networks:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity